# Is it possible to run Tango mobile messaging on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, crossplatform

Is there is a way to run Tango on current version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. According to [Tango's AppDB entry](//appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13730) it was considered garbage back in 2012 with Wine 1.5.8 and there's no newer report. Current Wine versions may work better though.